# Проверка формы: ФИО & Город

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста. Битый день пытаюсь составить регулярки для проверки Имени и фамилии, города.
допустим:

```
<?php
$name='Илья Трихлеб';
$location='Сумы';
?>
```

как в имя не допустить другие символы кроме русс букв и пробела и в локейшн - кроме русс букв?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^[а-яёА-ЯЁ\s]+$/u', $name)

preg_match('/^[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+$/u', $location)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('~[^а-яёА-ЯЁ ]~u', $name)) {
   echo "Имя введено не верно";
}
```

в городе может быть 2 слова + может писаться через тире.

```
if(preg_match('~[^а-яёА-ЯЁ\- ]~u', $location)) {
   echo "Город введен не верно";
}
```

Comment: И фамилия может писаться через тире: Мамин-Сибиряк

Comment: Не забываем: код Ё находятся не между А и Я. Поэтому ёЁ надо прописывать отдельно: ~[^а-яА-ЯёЁ ]~u.

Comment: Спасибо за исправление. Обновил ответ.